# XSLT to create hiearacy of xml nodes

Tags: xslt, hierarchy

Input payload is as below:

```
<Root>
  <Child1>Test1</Child1>
  <Child2>Test1</Child2> 
  <Child3>Test1</Child3> 
  <Child4>Test1</Child4>    
  <Child2>Test1</Child2>   
  <Child3>Test1</Child3>    
  <Child4>Test1</Child4>    
  <Child1>Test1</Child1>    
  <Child2>Test1</Child2>    
  <Child3>Test1</Child3>    
  <Child4>Test1</Child4>   
  <Child2>Test1</Child2>    
  <Child3>Test1</Child3>   
  <Child4>Test1</Child4> 
</Root>
```

Need this to be formatted in below format. Any ideas, please?

```
<Root>
  <Loop1>
    <Child1>Test1</Child1>
    <Loop2>
      <Child2>Test1</Child2>
      <Child3>Test1</Child3>
      <Child4>Test1</Child4>
    </Loop2>
    <Loop2>
      <Child2>Test1</Child2>
      <Child3>Test1</Child3>
      <Child4>Test1</Child4>
    </Loop2>
  </Loop1>
  <Loop1>
    <Child1>Test1</Child1>
    <Loop2>
      <Child2>Test1</Child2>
      <Child3>Test1</Child3>
      <Child4>Test1</Child4>
    </Loop2>
    <Loop2>
      <Child2>Test1</Child2>
      <Child3>Test1</Child3>
      <Child4>Test1</Child4>
    </Loop2>
  </Loop1>
</Root>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/25065#25065)?

Comment: I give this a +1 because I think it's an interesting task in XSLT. However, it would be nice if you showed us your attempts so far and also told us if this has to solved in XSLT 1.0 or whether you are permitted to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I want this to be in xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use `for-each-group group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Child1">
      <Loop1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="Child2">
          <Loop2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </Loop2>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </Loop1>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can we get this in xslt version 1.0...i get this error Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group'when i run